# pytest unittest, how to group test cases?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I am new to unit testing and trying to implement some in my latest project. However, I can't seem to get the structure quite right.
In the following example I have a bunch of redundant code and it still isn't working, with the @pytest.mark.parametrize

What I would like ideally is for my test_select_childnode to be run with various different games, but for each game I need to create a node and mcts object, which I then pass to the test along with an integer. I think I need parametrize in order to achieve this but it doesn't seem to be working in this example. The example was working when I directly fed the fixtures into the test_select_childnode, but then I would need to repeat that function for each game along with repeating the fixtures which seems like a lot of boilerplate I'm sure could be done smarter.

```
@pytest.fixture
def node_ttt():
    g = TicTacToeGame()
    node = Node(g)
    return node

@pytest.fixture
def mcts_ttt():
    g = TicTacToeGame()
    nnet = TicTacToeNNet(g,nn_args)
    model = NNetWrapper(g,nnet,nn_args)
    mcts_instance = MCTS(model, mcts_args)
    return mcts_instance


@pytest.mark.parametrize("mcts, node, action_idx", [
    (mcts_ttt, node_ttt, 0),
])


def test_select_childnode(mcts, node, action_idx):
    """
    Assert that childnode is creating a new node when needed.
    Assert that childnode is not creating a new node when not needed.
    """
    mcts.nodes[node.id] = node
    child_node = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
    child_node2 = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
    assert child_node != child_node2, "child nodes are not unique when they should be"
    mcts.add_node(child_node, node.id, action_idx)

    child_node2 = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
    assert child_node == child_node2, "accessing the same child node that we previously added, should not create a new node"




Testing started at 8:02 p.m. ...
Connected to pydev debugger (build 223.8617.48)
Launching pytest with arguments /home/tue/PycharmProjects/Hive_nn/tests/test_mcts.py --no-header --no-summary -q in /home/tue/PycharmProjects/Hive_nn/tests

============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_mcts.py::test_select_childnode[mcts_ttt-node_ttt-0] FAILED          [100%]
test_mcts.py:43 (test_select_childnode[mcts_ttt-node_ttt-0])
mcts = <function mcts_ttt at 0x7fe673be1f30>
node = <function node_ttt at 0x7fe673be1e10>, action_idx = 0

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("mcts, node, action_idx", [
        (mcts_ttt, node_ttt, 0),
    ])
    
    
    def test_select_childnode(mcts, node, action_idx):
        """
        Assert that childnode is creating a new node when needed.
        Assert that childnode is not creating a new node when not needed.
        """
>       mcts.nodes[node.id] = node
E       AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'nodes'

test_mcts.py:54: AttributeError




============================== 1 failed in 1.29s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you're passing references to the functions, hence the error `'function' object has no attribute 'nodes'`.

Instead, I think you want to pass the results of calling the functions:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("mcts, node, action_idx", [
    (mcts_ttt(), node_ttt(), 0),
])
```

There's also no need for the two functions to be decorated as fixtures at all unless you're using them as fixtures in other tests.

**Edit:**

As @akx mentioned in a comment, an alternative is to use `indirect=True` like this, so that the functions are not evaluated until the tests are run:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("mcts, node, action_idx", [
    (mcts_ttt, node_ttt, 0)
], indirect=True)
```

Comment: This will cause the fixture functions to be run at import time. `indirect=True` would be better.

Comment: Thanks @AKX. I've updated my answer to include this extra information.

Answer (score 0):

I read some more about pytest yesterday and based on that I changed my test to the following which works:

```
@pytest.fixture(params=[(TicTacToeGame(),TicTacToeNNet), (HiveGame(), HiveNNet)])
def mcts_node(request):
    g,nn_fnc = request.param
    nnet = nn_fnc(g,nn_args)
    model = NNetWrapper(g,nnet,nn_args)
    mcts_instance = MCTS(model, mcts_args)
    node = Node(g)
    return mcts_instance, node

class TestMcts:

    def test_child_nodes_are_unique(self,mcts_node):
        action_idx = 0
        mcts, node = mcts_node
        mcts.nodes[node.id] = node
        child_node = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
        child_node2 = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
        assert child_node != child_node2, "child nodes are not unique when they should be"

    def test_child_nodes_are_identical(self,mcts_node):
        action_idx = 0
        mcts, node = mcts_node
        mcts.nodes[node.id] = node
        child_node = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
        mcts.add_node(child_node, node.id, action_idx)
        child_node2 = mcts.select_childnode(node, action_idx)
        assert child_node == child_node2, "accessing the same child node that we previously added, should not create a new node"
```

I split the test into two tests that each has one assert, since that seems cleaner?
Would this be an acceptable way to do it? I am no longer using @pytest.mark.parametrize, but I can't quite figure out whether that is a problem or not.

Finally, this solution still has some annoying repetitive boilerplate, that I would like to reduce - the first 4 lines of both of these functions are the same and are still just setup code that I ideally want to only write once and then just have available to all tests in the class. I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
class TestMcts:

    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='class')
    def setup(self,mcts_node):
        self.action_idx = 0
        self.mcts, self.node = mcts_node
        self.mcts.nodes[self.node.id] = self.node
        self.child_node = self.mcts.select_childnode(self.node, self.action_idx)

    def test_child_nodes_are_unique(self):
        child_node2 = self.mcts.select_childnode(self.node, self.action_idx)
        assert self.child_node != child_node2, "child nodes are not unique when they should be"

    def test_child_nodes_are_identical(self,):
        self.mcts.add_node(self.child_node, self.node.id, self.action_idx)
        child_node2 = self.mcts.select_childnode(self.node, self.action_idx)
        assert self.child_node == child_node2, "accessing the same child node that we previously added, should not create a new node"
```

The error message I get is:

```
    def test_child_nodes_are_unique(self):
>       child_node2 = self.mcts.select_childnode(self.node, self.action_idx)
E       AttributeError: 'TestMcts' object has no attribute 'mcts'

test_mcts.py:65: AttributeError
```

So I guess the variables made in setup isn't available in the test